# Xdebug profiler and storing request data

Tags: php, xdebug, profiler

I'm trying to use the profiler feature of the xdebug in order to find the bottlenecks of my PHP code. I've managed to setup the xdebugger's profiler and everything. Most importantly, I have discovered that I need to enable *profiler append* so different requests won't overwrite eachother's gathered profile data. This way one *cachegrind.out* file will hold multiple parts each belonging to a different request. Now my problem is that I need to know request data for each part. By request data I mean GET / POST.

Is this possible? And I'm using KCacheGrind to visualize the profiler data.